# What is the best way to check npm dependencies for security issues?

Tags: node.js, security, npm, npm-install, node-modules

Specifically: what is the best way to check all dependencies including nested dependencies of packages listed in `dependencies`, `peerDependencies`, and `devDependencies` declared in `package.json` when using node.js?

The results of https://www.google.com/search?q=npm+check+dependencies+security do not look satisfactory so far.

Comment: The `npm install` command sometimes tells me to do `npm i npm@latest -g` then `npm audit`, which seems to do the trick. I would like to leave this question open for more seasoned NPM experts before posting this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Snyk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snyk)

> Snyk helps you find, fix and monitor known vulnerabilities in Node.js npm, Ruby and Java dependencies, both on an ad hoc basis and as part of your CI (Build) system.

Comment: Thanks @alejandro-estrada I just upvoted your answer. I would probably want to check the results of both Snyk and npm audit.

Answer (score 1):

Most recently the `npm audit` [was introduced](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities). I've tested snyk 2-3 years ago, can't anything positive or negative for the current state. There are other tools as well, and ways of finding out vulnerable packages. I would suggest to watch the talk "[Analysis of an Exploited NPM Package](https://youtu.be/2cyib2MgvdM)" by Jarrod Overson. Useful just to understand that there always ways to exploit package repositories, especially full of open-source :)